# Paypal NVP API: is zipcode required for UK, Canada, Denmark?

Tags: paypal

From PayPal integration guide (PP_NVPAPI_DeveloperGuide_v89.pdf) I found out that zipcode for billing/shipping address is required for U.S. and may be required for other countries. Can someone clear for me is UK, Canada, Denmark included to this "other-coutries" list or zipcode(postal code) is not needed there?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Zip Code is mandatory for all countries. Source: Open up Paypal shipping, every country requires a zip code to proceed.